# Message drop-down options box in chat is moving while scrolling through chat

Tags: bug, design, chat

I know the question title might sound weird. Let me explain.

When the drop-down of message is clicked and the box with options (like reply to message, flag) is displayed and one is scrolling through the chat, even the box is moving. For a better understanding, see this video:

[image: Video of scrolling through chat when the options box of the message in chat is open]

The box shouldn't move when one is scrolling through chat.

---

For example, when we click on the share button on a post and scroll through the page, the share box doesn't move like how it does in chat. See this video for understanding:

[image: Video of scrolling through page when the share box in post is open]

Comment: https://prnt.sc/vq1zzv

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. You scroll, so the location of your cursor changes on the screen. Hence there will be a different button under your cursor when you're finished scrolling.

Comment: @Ollie I don't think so. I've edited my question. Please check.

Comment: @technastic_tc I see.  Same with the close vote dropdown...

Comment: @Luuklag After re-reading your comment multiple times I got what you're trying to say. But I guess you might have misunderstood my question. I've edited it to make it more clear. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

I personally consider this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

When new chat messages are sent, the chat script will naturally scroll downward to accommodate the new message. With this dropdown open, if more messages are sent, it would feel a bit weird if the dropdown started moving upwards with the rest of the messages. If you've got that dropdown open and are about to click "flag for moderator" for example, you might miss your click if a message is sent in between your intent to click and your actual click if your presented fix was implemented. I can definitely see this happening in a chatroom that is extremely active at that given time. That wayward click would make the box disappear, and pretty much ruin your attempt at a flag. Thus, the fact that this box *doesn't* move helps to ensure that you don't lose the box as the chat scrolls away.

I recognize that this is different than the main site's experience with similar dropdowns and input boxes, but it's *mostly* impossible for the page to scroll downwards automatically (without user action) on the main page the same way that chat can. The user *has* to manually scroll. In such an environment, those dropdowns not scrolling with the user's scroll is acceptable. It's worth noting, though, that flag dialogs and close vote dialogs *do* scroll along with the user's scroll.

Comment: Damn!  I was literally four seconds away from saying the same.  The script is also set to `position:  fixed`, versus the `position:  relative` that the other dropdowns are, so it might still be an FR.

Comment: I could see this being a FR as well. If it was converted to such, I would prefer it be optional, though. Also... Ninja'd ;D @Ollie

Comment: @Spevacus Why can't the chat understand the difference between a user scrolling the chat and the chat automatically scrolling when new messages are posted in chat?

Comment: I assume that it could, but that would be getting into [tag:feature-request] territory, not so much bug territory.

Comment: @Spevacus I guess I'll be bad at expressing my question in words. Already the community down-voted this question a lot because they initially misunderstood my wording :(